# Wordpress native thickbox language

Tags: language, thickbox

Is there any clean way (not overwriting wp-includes\js\thickbox\thickbox.js file) to translate english next/ prev/ image # of # and Close tooltip in Wordpress native Thickbox script?

Answer (score 1):

[Localize Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language) or write and load special localization for your language specialy for thickbox. Thickbox dialogs support localization provided by WP

Update - Let's Check

```
1. You have uncomented string <code>define('WPLANG', 'pl_PL');</code> in your wp-config.php
2. You have localization files in wp-content/languages/
```

Comment: Hi! I have installed polish version of Wordpress and have translated words like "Next" in pl_PL.po / pl_PL.mo located in "languages" folder. What else I can do?

Comment: as far as i see polan translation (provided by pl.wordpress.org) already contain translation for thickbox. its should work in wp-admin now with dali/poperednie/obraz words... can you confirm it?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand last sentence (its should work in wp-admin now with dali/poperednie/obraz words...)

Comment: Thickbox should be localized in polish if you using Polish wordpress (with localization files and anabed WPLANG in wp-config)

Comment: I have 'WPLANG', 'pl_PL' in wp-config and polish language in whole WP except Thickbox... By the way, to call Thickbox I'm using a WP Thickbox Integration Plugin but it uses native thickbox.js

Comment: Good. as far as i see problem resolved? (I just check) plugin catch localizaton and thickbox is localized (had test it with Ukrainian langauge).

Comment: Unfortunately Thickbox is still in english language :-/

Comment: Plese check do you have anbled options which i describe in answer. What is your wp verson? Is it now in Polish?

Comment: Hi! I've checked two options (define('WPLANG', 'pl_PL') in wp-config.php and localization files in wp-content/languages). They're correct. Howeverin language files I don't have strong from Thickbox (for example: "Image # of #'). I'am using 3.3.1 WordPress version.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. Newest WordPress version has translated Thickbox version! Thank You Code Monkey for help!

Anyway I still wonder why in version 3.3.1 the translation doesn't work (I've checked pl_PL.po file in wp-content\languages and there is translation pointing to script-loader.php where actually are strings from Thickbox for translation! :-/

Comment: you wellcome. pick the answer =)